# Compute indexed tensor multiplication with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to compute the following with sympy:

[image: linkToImage]

Where `I` is a 3x3 identity matrix. The end use is to use this with symbolic matrices.

I have the following:

```
import sympy as sp

I = sp.eye(3)

Missing operations with sympy
```

With numpy I can just use the `einsum` function and have:

```
import numpy as np
I = np.eye(3)
Res = (np.einsum("ij,kl->ijkl", I, I)
+ np.einsum("ik,jl->ijkl", I, I)
+ np.einsum("il,jk->ijkl", I, I))
```

However, `einsum` will not accept sympy's objects for this operation.
How can I compute this with sympy?

Answer (score 0):

While the notation makes the `einsum` expression convenient, it isn't a matrix-product.  It's more like an extended outer product.  There's no sum-of-products:

```
In [22]: I = np.eye(3)
    ...: Res = (
    ...:     np.einsum("ij,kl->ijkl", I, I)
    ...:     + np.einsum("ik,jl->ijkl", I, I)
    ...:     + np.einsum("il,jk->ijkl", I, I)
    ...: )

In [23]: Res
Out[23]: 
array([[[[3., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]],

        [[0., 1., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 1., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 3., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.],
         [0., 1., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 0., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 1.],
         [0., 1., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 3.]]]])

In [24]: Res.shape
Out[24]: (3, 3, 3, 3)
```

In `numpy` we can use `broadcasting` to do the same thing:

```
In [25]: res1 = I[:,:,None,None]*I + I[:,None,:,None]*I[None,:,None,:]+I[:,None,None,:]*I[None,:,:,Non
    ...: e]

In [26]: res1.shape
Out[26]: (3, 3, 3, 3)

In [27]: np.allclose(Res, res1)
Out[27]: True
```

Your `sp.eye` produces a `MutableDenseMatrix`

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/dense.html#sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix

Feel free to study its docs.  My impression is that sympy matrices don't implement multidimensional arrays with anything like the power of `numpy`.